# Are there alternatives for creating large container files that are cross platform?

Tags: windows, macos, cross-platform, file-format, container-file

Previously, I asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79136/how-do-i-create-a-container-file).

The problem is the demands of our file structure are very high.

For instance, we're trying to create a container with up to 4500 files and 500mb data.

The file structure of this container consists of

- SQLite DB (under 1mb)
- Text based xml-like file

  Images inside a dynamic folder structure that make up the rest of the 4,500ish files

  After the initial creation the images files are read only with the exception of deletion.

  The small db is used regularly when the container is accessed.

Tar, Zip and the likes are all too slow (even with 0 compression). Slow is subjective I know, but to untar a container of this size is over 20 seconds.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us if it's read-only or read/write/create/delete access to the files.

Comment: Or, more generally, what kind of read operation you want to perform. If it is only creation of the container given all files, then extraction of all files, I don't think tar will be slow. So you must be doing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things.

1) What Timothy Walters said is right on, I'll go in to more detail.

2) 4500 files and 500Mb of data is simply a lot of data and disk writes. If you're operating on the entire dataset, it's going to be slow. Just I/O truth.

3) As others have mentioned, there's no detail on the use case.

If we assume a read only, random access scenario, then what Timothy says is pretty much dead on, and implementation is straightforward.

In a nutshell, here is what you do.

You concatenate all of the files in to a single blob. While you are concatenating them, you track their filename, the file length, and the offset that the file starts within the blob. You write that information out in to a block of data, sorted by name. We'll call this the Table of Contents, or TOC block.

Next, then, you concatenate the two files together. In the simple case, you have the TOC block first, then the data block.

When you wish to get data from this format, search the TOC for the file name, grab the offset from the begining of the data block, add in the TOC block size, and read FILE_LENGTH bytes of data. Simple.

If you want to be clever, you can put the TOC at the END of the blob file. Then, append at the very end, the offset to the start of the TOC. Then you lseek to the end of the file, back up 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your number size), take THAT value and lseek even farther back to the start of your TOC. Then you're back to square one. You do this so you don't have to rebuild the archive twice at the beginning.

If you lay out your TOC in blocks (say 1K byte in size), then you can easily perform a binary search on the TOC. Simply fill each block with the File information entries, and when you run out of room, write a marker, pad with zeroes and advance to the next block. To do the binary search, you already know the size of the TOC, start in the middle, read the first file name, and go from there. Soon, you'll find the block, and then you read in the block and scan it for the file. This makes it efficient for reading without having the entire TOC in RAM. The other benefit is that the blocking requires less disk activity than a chained scheme like TAR (where you have to crawl the archive to find something).

I suggest you pad the files to block sizes as well, disks like work with regular sized blocks of data, this isn't difficult either.

Updating this without rebuilding the entire thing is difficult. If you want an updatable container system, then you may as well look in to some of the simpler file system designs, because that's what you're really looking for in that case.

As for portability, I suggest you store your binary numbers in network order, as most standard libraries have routines to handle those details for you.

Comment: No, tar is a streaming format, the file information is associated with each file, not centralized in a single block. If you want to scan a tar file for a specific entry you have to follow the chain through potentially the entire archive.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be doing arbitrary file system operations on your container (say, creation, deletion of new files in the container, overwriting existing files, appending), I think you should go for some kind of file system. Allocate a large file, then create a file system structure in it.

There are several options for the file system available: for both Berkeley UFS and Linux ext2/ext3, there are user-mode libraries available. It might also be possible that you find a FAT implementation somewhere. Make sure you understand the structure of the file system, and pick one that allows for extending - I know that ext2 is fairly easy to extend (by another block group), and FAT is difficult to extend (need to append to the FAT).

Alternatively, you can put a virtual disk format yet below the file system, allowing arbitrary remapping of blocks. Then "free" blocks of the file system don't need to appear on disk, and you can allocate the virtual disk much larger than the real container file will be.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that you're only going to need read-only access to the files why not just merge them all together and have a second "index" file (or an index in the header) that tells you the file name, start position and length. All you need to do is seek to the start point and read the correct number of bytes. The method will vary depending on your language but it's pretty straight forward in most of them.

The hardest part then becomes creating your data file + index, and even that is pretty basic!

Comment: Isn't that basically the equivalent of Tar, with your index file contained within the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

An ISO disk image might do the trick.  It should be able to hold that many files easily, and is supported by many pieces of software on all the major operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank-you for expanding your question, it helps a lot in providing better answers.

Given that you're going to need a SQLite database anyway, have you looked at the performance of putting it all into the database? My experience is based around SQL Server 2000/2005/2008 so I'm not positive of the capabilities of SQLite but I'm sure it's going to be a pretty fast option for looking up records and getting the data, while still allowing for delete and/or update options.

Usually I would not recommend to put files inside the database, but given that the total size of all images is around 500MB for 4500 images you're looking at a little over 100K per image right? If you're using a dynamic path to store the images then in a slightly more normalized database you could have a "ImagePaths" table that maps each path to an ID, then you can look for images with that PathID and load the data from the BLOB column as needed.

The XML file(s) could also be in the SQLite database, which gives you a single 'data file' for your app that can move between Windows and OSX without issue. You can simply rely on your SQLite engine to provide the performance and compatability you need.

How you optimize it depends on your usage, for example if you're frequently needing to get all images at a certain path then having a PathID (as an integer for performance) would be fast, but if you're showing all images that start with "A" and simply show the path as a property then an index on the ImageName column would be of more use.

I am a little concerned though that this sounds like premature optimization, as you really need to find a solution that works 'fast enough', abstract the mechanics of it so your application (or both apps if you have both Mac and PC versions) use a simple repository or similar and then you can change the storage/retrieval method at will without any implication to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Solid File System](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) - it seems to be what you need.